# GWT/SMARTGWT *.ics file generator

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt, icalendar

I am new to GWT and I am using smartGWT extension. What I want to do is to put the event from Calendar widget to *.ics file so that I can load it easily to my Outlook Calendar. Has anyone heard about any tools for that?

Tools that create .ics in java from data in any format are also very welcome. I found iCal4j but I'm not very happy with that.